# Linking to Python import library in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: python, visual-studio, import, linker

I have a C++ application that has embedded Python. I'm building with Visual Studio 2005. When I try to link to python26.lib, I get a number of unresolved symbols, all of which begin with "__imp":

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Initialize referenced in function _main

python26.lib is an import library (installed by the Python 2.6 installer). What do I have to do to resolve these symbols? They do exist in the import library (dumpbin /all shows them). Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like I was trying to link a 64-bit Python library to a 32-bit application. I wish the linker would tell me something other than "unresolved symbol." Linking to the 32-bit library fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try to include `C:\WINDOWS\system32\python26.dll` in your references. `python26.lib` contains the symbol names for the main DLL.

Comment: I thought you weren't supposed to link directly to dll's, but rather to the corresponding .lib. When I try to link directly to python26.dll, I get a linker error (LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file). According to MSDN, this error can occur if you pass a dll to the linker instead of a .obj.