# Interfacing python with c++

Tags: c++, python, interface

I am trying to interface python with C++. I am using Visual Studio Express 2012. I also have an enthought python 2.7 distribution. When I tried to build a Release on Win 32 with the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "C:/Python27/include/Python.h"
#include "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h"

using namespace std;


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{  
   int x = 1;
   PyObject *mod1;
   Py_Initialize();
   return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Initialize
```

Please help, any ideas more than welcome.

Comment: Uh... did you try linking?

Comment: It is a linking issue you can read the already asked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658879/linking-to-python-import-library-in-visual-studio-2005

Comment: also add Python to your include path instead of using absolute path

Comment: Sorry I am at a loss as to how you mean, I am trying to build it, which automatically links it. I just cant build it due to those errors. I also tried to go through that post but wasnt clear. I apologize if I am being clumsy, but please let me know how to fix that error to build my application. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `C:\Python27\libs` to your library paths and add `python27.lib` to your dependencies.

For that:

```
Go to project properties -> Configuration properties -> Linker.
Go to ->General and set the "Additional Library directories"
```

In this field you add `C:\Python27\libs`.

After that:

```
Go to Linker -> Input and set the "Additional Dependencies"
```

In this field you add `python27.lib`.

Also you should add `C:\Python27\include` to your include directories and just do:

```
#include <Python.h>
```

Comment: I did the above and also changed to 64 bit and solved my problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to link a 64 Bit python library to a 32-Bit Application